# simple calculator code gives extreme numbers

Tags: c++

When i run the code i get extreme numbers like 1973555552 for addition

ive tried checking to see if its the ide(codeblocks)  but i dont think it is.

the value i entered for x was 2 and the value for y was 1  so why does it give extrme answers like  1973555552 for additon ?

```
 int main() 
 {
 int x ;
 int y ;
 int addition = x + y ;
 int subtraction =   x - y ;
 int multiplication = x * y ;
 float division = x /y ;

  cout<< " enter first number :"<<endl;
  cin >> x  ;
  cout<< " enter second number :" << endl;
  cin >> y ;

 cout<< " addition is :"<< addition ;
 cout<< " subtraction is: "<< subtraction;
 cout<< " multiplilcation is: "<< multiplication;
 cout<< "division is :" << division;

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Expressions in C++ are instructions not equations. Variable `addition` for example would not magically change its value after you changed `x` and `y` latrer unless you do that assignment again. So simply move those declarations after you enter values for `x` and `y`

Comment: Always turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang) and pay attention to them.

Comment: the value i entered for x was 2 and for y it was 1 .  why is it giving me extreme answers

Comment: @geoffreycadbury -- C++ programs run top-down.  Maybe this is the point you're missing.  C++ doesn't magically jump to a previous line and perform the calculation.

Comment: Because you assigned values to `x` and `y` after you used them to calculate.

Comment: thanks slava, paulmckenzie , rorschach and thanks once again to slava

Comment: ` int x ;
 int y ;
 int addition = x + y ;` - You have Undefined Behaviour right there. Neither `x` nor `y` has been initialized, so reading them is UB. Whatever `addition` is after that is unknown and in fact the entire program is Undefined. This is *not* a valid C++ program and any result you get is valid. You can have *no* expectations from this code.